# CSS code for div with specific in Shiny does not work

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  includeCSS("C:/Users/Marc/Dropbox/PROJECTEN/Lopend/css_test/www/styles.css"),

  tags$div(id="myfirstdiv", "Hallo"),
  tags$h1("Hallo")


)
server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server= server)
```

I combined this with a styles.css file that is placed in my www folder. The css file looks like this:

```
#myfirstdiv {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-color: coral;
  color: blue;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
}

h1{
color: green;
}
```

This is that when I run the app the css code for H1 is working (text becomes green). The css code for the div with id="myfirstdiv" is not working however.

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: sidenote, I think it is better practice to include your stylesheet as follows: `tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css")`, that is also how it is explained [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html). That way, if another user runs your code, he will not run into errors because his path may be different.

Answer (score 0):

css works for me, and top-hallo is blue. Maybe you forgot:

```
border-style: solid;
```